# how to use C libs in java

Tags: java, c, dylib

I do have a question, I had to develop an app on java but the app need to access to a USB device. To do this I'm using a mtp stack and the mtp is done through a dylib. What I need to make the app is from java to access to the c api. I plan to develop a wrapper to convert c api to a java class and only use the java class to interact with the api.

I have seen some

```
JNIEXPORT command
```

But I'm not quiet sure on how to use it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> JNA provides Java programs easy access to native shared libraries
>   without writing anything but Java code - no JNI or native code is
>   required. This functionality is comparable to Windows' Platform/Invoke
>   and Python's types.

Seems like [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna) its an option here

Also like you say JNI could be a good option here, [check the tips from android developers page](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html)

This [tutorial of JNI](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaNativeInterface.html) can help you to

Comment: @Seb did you find the way? =D

Comment: @seb i think im going to delete my answer since i don't want to confuse newcomers, or did this answer help you?